# Sharing global object with typescript version

Tags: typescript, electron

The [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#how-to-share-data-between-web-pages) shows how to share data between pages:

```
// In the main process.
global.sharedObject = {
  someProperty: 'default value'
}
```

but with [Typescript](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript) version, we get this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'sharedObject' does not exist on type 'Global'.

Comment: you could use the `global['sharedObject']` syntaxis and the compiler should stop complaining. Not the ideal solution but it should do the trick!

Comment: Still get `error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Global' has no index signature.`

Comment: You can also typecast global as any `(global as any).sharedObject` but it's also a cheat. In this case it seems like the Global definition that Typescript is using doesn't know the sharedObject property. You can extended yourself but if I could guess it's using the node Global definition instead of the Electron(?) definition. I have to clarify that I don't know if Electron has that type definition.